# How can I draw a contour line and edge line for deformation of a STL file

Tags: python, modifiers, sculpt, surface-deform

[image]
I am wangdering if blender can achieve the functions as the impage shows?

Imported a STL file in the blender.
1.draw a contour line which can limit deformation range,like the blue line.
2.dras a edge line inside the contour line which can contronl the direction and size of deformation,like the red line.

Woud someone please give me some suggestions or tips.Thx a lot.

Comment: Hello. I think you can do something like this in Blender, but not using the same tools. What is the end goal here ?

Comment: It's orthotics(brace) design work, we want to design a 3D file, usually a part of human body, about deformation operations according to biomechanics.
I have tried 'mask' tool, it can create  a contour  which can limit deformation range, but it's hard to  contronl the direction and size of deformation like the red line as above image.
Would you plese give some suggetions? thx a lot.